How to permute a single wire to no wire in quantikz?
When I try to permute the bottom wire to the middle row, where there were no wire to begin with, there is an extral foot wire that I hope can be erased:

\begin{quantikz}
    & \permute{3} \setwiretype{n}&\\
    \setwiretype{n}& & \setwiretype{q} \\
    & \permute{0} &
\end{quantikz}

If I didn't use the \setwiretype{q} on the middle row, the permutation wire is not long enough
\begin{quantikz}
    & \permute{3} \setwiretype{n}&\\
    \setwiretype{n}& & \\
    & \permute{0} &
\end{quantikz}


A complete example is
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}
\begin{document}
\title{Example}
\maketitle
\begin{quantikz}
& \permute{3} \setwiretype{n}&\\
\setwiretype{n}& &\setwiretype{q}
\\
&\permute{0} &
\end{quantikz}
\begin{quantikz}
& \permute{3} \setwiretype{n}&\\
\setwiretype{n}& &
\\
&\permute{0} &
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}


welcome! can you expand your code fragments into a complete example we can compile to reproduce your current output?

@cfr Thanks for the comment! A complete example is added.

There is a method that works for my question: push a phantom element into the wire. The code fragment is
\begin{quantikz}
    & \permute{3} \setwiretype{n}&\\
    \setwiretype{n}& \push{\phantom{--}} & \setwiretype{q} \\
    & \permute{0} &
\end{quantikz}


